# Use the regex.h C library in Cython

Tags: python, regex, external, cython

I want to use the regex.h library in my Cython code because the build-in re module seems to be very slow but I have a lot of trouble doing it. I understand that I have to create a .pxd file and use it as an external module in my code but I'm really new in Python/Cython..

**This is my regex.pxd file:**

```
cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef char const_char "const char"

cdef extern from "regex.h" nogil:
    int regcomp(regex_t* PREG, const char* REGEX, int CFLAGS)
    int regexec(const regex_t *PREG, const char *STRING, size_t NMATCH, regmatch_t   PMATCH[], int EFLAGS)
```

I'm running the command : `$python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

**And I'm getting this error after doing**:

```
regex.pxd:6:27: Expected ')', found '*'
```

Do you have any other ideas on how I could use the `regex.h` library within my `Cython` code?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to Cython version 0.18 or later. (Note: the question was asked before that release)

The relevant [release note from that version](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/ReleaseNotes-0.18) is "C `const` declarations are supported in the language"

Answer (score 1):

From previous experience, I think the `const` specifier is upsetting it. From the Cython docs on [interfacing with external C code](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html), under *Referencing C header files*:

> Don’t use const. Cython doesn’t know anything about const, so just leave it out. Most of the time this shouldn’t cause any problem, although on rare occasions you might have to use a cast.

I copied your code into a .pxd file on my machine and Cython gave the same error. Removing the `const` bits got rid of that error.